# How to get/craft non-advanced colour crystals

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've recently started playing SWTOR with my girlfriend (she's FTP) and I'm trying to get her a colour crystal for her lightsaber because right now she doesn't have one equipped. I've been levelling up artifice but can only seem to craft advanced crystals which she can't use...

How can I get the plain old crystals that she can use?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn basic (green/blue level) crystals early on in Artificing.  At Artificing level 80, you will learn more colors of crystals.  Reaching the skill to craft Advanced crystals won't remove the knowledge to craft the basic ones.

At level 50+, though, the best crystals are all Advanced ones.  You may need the Artifact Authorization to use them, which can typically be bought from the GTN with credits if you don't want to spend actual money.

Comment: I'm artifice level 131 and have only been able to learn advanced red and blue crystals from my trainer (red around 80 and I started with the knowledge for blue). Do I learn the basic ones from somewhere else?